# Error sending email with Office 365

Tags: exchange, smtp, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

My company has Office 365.

We use account for send email (SMTP/SSL)
https://www.gmass.co/blog/office365-smtp/#office

We get error similar like this, but using Exchange Online
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/817963/error-in-processing-451-470-temporary-server-error.html

We get the error:

**Error in processing. 4.3.111 Temporary server error. Please try again later MRH1 [Hostname=PA4PR04MB9341.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com]**

it is intermittent.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting ?

*Updated:*

Support recomended:

1- Check concurrent connections (max 3) and how much applications use the email account for sending.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/send-emails/smtp-submission-improvements

2- Check sending limits for Exchange on line.

• 30 messages per minute
• Recipient rate limit of 10,000 recipients per day

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits

3- Check that source IP has SPF register

4- Check TLS version using by the app. Must be 1.2 version.
Other case, enable the parameter for TLS versions older.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/new-opt-in-endpoint-available-for-smtp-auth-clients-still/ba-p/2659652

1. Set AllowLegacyTLSClients from cmdlet Set-TransportConfig to "True"
2. Older clients and apps must be configured using endpoint smtp-legacy.office365.com

Comment: Open a support case from your Office 365 tenant. It's free of charge.

Comment: updated with info by Microsoft support

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm if all users in your organization encounter this issue? Running [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365OutboundSmtp/input) to test outbound mails and check if there any other error messages.

In addition, Comparing steps in the [blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission) and check if you are configured incorrectly in somewhere.